# convert a document in doc

Tags: php, html

```
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

help of this i can convert a file into CSv
but i want a file into .doc
when i change the header it ill not convert the file 
it not able to pik data from the database

how can i change a file in .doc

Comment: You are aware that .doc and .csv are two vastly different data formats? Simply changing the header won't magically turn one format into the other. You will need to *create an actual .doc file*.

Comment: or where we get the tutorial can you tell me

Comment: You can try using PHPWord (http://phpword.codeplex.net) though this only writes to the newer .docx format of Word

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use COM interface to control Word application and create word document that way. Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [JODConvert](http://0x.vc/1q/). It's a java based tool. but can easily be called from PHP by using the passthru or shell_exec functions